# Quoting shell env vars in Makefile

Tags: linux, makefile

I thought I understood that simply-expanded variables got their value *once*,  when the `Makefile` is read -- but I've got confused:

```
var := $$RANDOM

echo:
        @echo v1: $(var)
        @echo v2: $(var)
```

With result

```
$ make
v1: 11478
v2: 24064
```

So how come the shell env var is referenced twice?

I see that `var := $(shell echo $$RANDOM)` don't do the second value assignment -- how is this machinery different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply-expanded variables are MAKE constructs.  Indeed, that variable is only expanded one time, *by make*.  But, it expands into a shell variable:

```
var := $$RANDOM
```

now the value of the `var` variable in make is the static string `$RANDOM` and make will never expand it again.  You can determine this by doing something like:

```
var := $(info expanding RANDOM)$$RANDOM
```

and you'll see it only prints `expanding RANDOM` one time.

But, this rule:

```
echo:
        @echo v1: $(var)
        @echo v2: $(var)
```

invokes *shell* two times and each time passing the static string `$RANDOM`, which the *shell* expands, each time the shell is invoked, and you get different answers.  Basically, make is running:

```
/bin/sh -c 'echo v1: $RANDOM'
/bin/sh -c 'echo v2: $RANDOM'
```

If you change it to this:

```
var := $(shell echo $$RANDOM)
```

Here, make is invoking the shell, one time, and assigning the *result of that shell command* to the variable `var`.  So after this, `var` contains the literal string `12345` or whatever the result is, not `$RANDOM`.

BTW, you should add:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
```

to your makefile, because `$RANDOM` is a bash feature that is not available in the POSIX shell, and make always invokes `/bin/sh` by default: on some systems `/bin/sh` is the same thing as bash but on other systems, it isn't.